# Cannot create a list in model (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am new to ASP.NET and MVC.

I am trying to display a list of dates in a view that are within the 2019 calendar year.  I have seen demos of people going about this in two ways:

1. Formulate a LINQ query and pass the query as a parameter to the view.
2. Make a list out of the data in their model and pass the data to the view through a foreach loop.

In my case, my model will not let me create a list of dates.

```
public partial class PeriodEndDates2
{
    public string payPeriodYear { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime periodEndDate { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime ffsPayDate { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime indPayDate { get; set; }

    public List<periodEndDates> MyDatesList { get; set; }
}
```

Error Message: The type or namespace name 'periodEndDates' could not be found.

In the demos I am watching, no one seems to have this problem.  It seems as if the compiler knows that you are trying to create a list out of the data in your model and automatically creates a type called 'periodEndDates' or whatever they name the type.

Comment: `PeriodEndDates2`  vs `PeriodEndDates`  ?

Comment: Just how it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't know about the class periodEndDates

Try this instead:

```
public partial class PeriodEndDates2
{
  public string payPeriodYear { get; set; }

  public System.DateTime periodEndDate { get; set; }

  public System.DateTime ffsPayDate { get; set; }

  public System.DateTime indPayDate { get; set; }

  public List<DateTime> MyDatesList { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create the object and populate the list of dates.

Comment: Will this populate MyDatesList with periodEndDates?  Because that is what I am intending to do.

Comment: Basically, I need to populate the list with data from a sql table.